# Application permission issues on OS X, when distributing application

Tags: xcode, macos

we are making an Application for OS X, however, when the .app is copied on another MAC, we have problems with reading and writing files

on one MAC, everything works great from the start...
the other one will not write certain files and another 2mac will not write certain different files

if i go to show application contents and wants to edit the file by myself, i get a writing permission denied

**how to distribute an MAC application so there are no such issues? so all files can be read and write by the current user**

does there have to be some authorization or code sign, or smth. different in this form, in addition to normal code?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your application tries to write files within its own application bundle.  The correct solution here is: *DON'T DO THAT*! The only time your application bundle should be written to is when it's installed or updated.

Files that the application needs to write to should be stored in the user's home folder, generally under ~/Library.  See [this note in Apple's dev docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW11).

- Preference and settings files in ~/Library/Preferences/<appbundleid>.plist; use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUserDefaults).
- Data the app manages for the user in ~/Library/Application Support/<appname> (the docs say to use the bundleid, but everyone -- Apple included -- uses the app name instead).
- Cache files in ~/Library/Caches/<appbundleid>.
- Temp files, use [NSTemporaryDirectory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/NSTemporaryDirectory)
- If you need to share settings & files between users, that should generally go in /Library/Application Support/<appname>, except that you really shouldn't be doing that at all.

Comment: yes, but if i on my MAC try to save files under ~/Library/Application Support/AppName/ using std::ofstream file; i get an error... but when i save inside the App, everything is OK... therefore iam saving inside the app bundle

Comment: i also tried ~/Library/Application Support/com.COMNAME.APPNAME/ which i specified inside plist, but the result is the same :(

Comment: For reference, it looks like the problem [was solved in this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993527/c-mac-os-x-cannot-write-to-library-application-support-appname).

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've always used PackageMaker to create installers.  An installation package can authenticate with root privileges so you can set permissions after the install.  I don't have it in front of me right now but if you look around you should be able to see a Post-Installer script line.  Write a shell script that manually sets the permissions of each file you have in question and then have the package execute that script after the install is finished.

You can find PackageMaker at /Developer/Applications/Utilities/PackageMaker

Comment: but exectly this happens also to me http://compgroups.net/comp.sys.mac.apps/PackageMaker-not-installing-my-app i tried the installer from XCode 3.2 and also 4, but nothing installs, even the installer package has 150MB and also there is an instalation progress, corresponding to that 150MB, there is no error, but also no file is put inside the app folder