# C++ MAC OS X cannot write to ~/Library/Application Support/<appname>

Tags: c++, file, macos, std

If i save files inside the `.app` bundle, it saves OK, but apple recommends saving files inside the Application Support
under

```
~/Library/Application Support/appname
```

or

```
~/Library/Application Support/bundleid
```

I tried both, but I am always getting an exception. I am getting a path to the Application Support, which is

```
/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/com.company.appname/
```

or

```
/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/AppName/
```

`com.company.appname` is specified correctly inside my `info.plist`, and `AppName` is `product AppName.app`, so the paths seems correct.

```
{
    FilepathProcessor::pathForFile(fpath, "menustate", ".sav", 
                                   PATH_TO_DESTINATION_SAVE_LOAD_FOLDER);

    std::ofstream file;
    file.exceptions(std::ofstream::eofbit | std::ofstream::failbit | 
                    std::ofstream::badbit);
    INFO_ARG("prepare to save to '%s'", fpath.c_str());

    try {
        file.open(fpath.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | 
                  std::ios::trunc);
        ERROR_IF_ARG(!file.is_open(), "couldnt open file for saving at '%s'",
                     fpath.c_str(), return);

        //will pass this point

        //exception happens by first write
        WRITE_INT_TO_BINFILE(file, episode);

        //...

    } 
    catch (std::ofstream::failure e) {
        ERROR_IF_ARG(true, "exception %s", e.what(), return);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Output :

```
INFO : prepare to save to '/Users/myname/Library/Application
       Support/com.comapny.appname/menustate.sav' [CALLED BY : saveToFile]

ERROR! 
    Text : exception basic_ios::clear
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directory is **not** automatically created for you. Before saving the file, you first need to check if the directory exists, and if not, you need to create the directory.